# Error while converting gridview into pdf format using iTextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having gridview in which in few records it has image and in few records it didn't have image which gives error while converting it to pdf format.This code works fine if each row have images but not in case if any record didn't have image. Can anyone suggest me what to do with code so that my error can be resolve
here is my code:

```
 protected void  Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grdview();
         string file = "testc" + ".pdf";
    string attachment = string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", file);
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    Panel1.RenderControl(hw);        
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    iTextSharp.text.Document pdfdoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
    pdfdoc.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    pdfdoc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A2);

    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfdoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfdoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfdoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);

    pdfdoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfdoc);
    Response.End();

    }
```

Image what error appears while conversion
[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Joonas Usually it's unclear where exactly it gives error cus as far as i've seen most of the times the pdf gets generated without error but it just won't open sayin corrupt file. I guess she is facing the same kind of problem

Comment: Kamna are you really sure that is your problem? I mean absence of image gives error? and what kind of error if any as I just like @joonas would like to know you are facing?

Comment: if you get error exactly for the reason you have specified, I would suggest, you add a default image too in your gridview in case of absent images. it could be anything even a plane white backgroung image or an image saying NA or anything

Comment: i posted the error image in my question plz have a look

Comment: i cant add image by myself because its route itenarary which only entered by admin .

Comment: I'd write the generated HTML to a file and examine the source. There might be some links to unreachable resources. Your source might still generate img-tags for 'missing' images and the src-tag might be something unreachable.

Comment: show the code that binds image with your gridview, and I am not saying to access admin rights, just keep a dummy default pic in your application folder which you can access in case there is no image

Comment: but i can't do that now because the users already entered many records without image. Can you suggest me how to bind default image  in http//localhost format that i already using.

Comment: my source code of image binding and after that the function i used for null image from database.                          <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="50px" ImageUrl='<%#FixPath(Eval("image",GetImageUrl("{0}"))) %>'/>  public string FixPath(object path)
    {
        if (path == DBNull.Value)
        {
            return "Image/nopic.jpg";
        }
        else
        {
            return (string)path;
        }
    }